# How to insert an array of objects into a mapping table - Sequelize

Tags: sql-server, node.js, sequelize.js

We have two tables - ticket and device. A mapper table 'ticketdevice_map' will have ticket_id(FK), device_id(FK) and some other values.
Associations are shown below:

```
ticketdevice_map.belongsTo(collection.device, {
        as: 'device',
        foreignKey: 'device_id'
    })

    ticketdevice_map.belongsTo(collection.ticket, {
        as: 'ticket',
        foreignKey: 'ticket_id'
    })
```

A ticket can have a number of devices associated with it. Now, when I create a ticket how can I insert this array of devices into the 'ticketdevice_map' table.

example:

```
{
"abc_id": "B222",
"devices": [{
    "device_id": 200,
    "reg_id": "aa",
    "reg_color": "red",
},{
    "device_id": 201,
    "reg_id": "aa",
    "reg_color": "red",
}]
```

}

in mapper table it should be inserted like,

```
ticket_id device_id reg_color
 1          200       red
 1          201       red
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sequelize this code will help you.

```
models.tblTicket.findOne({
where : {
    ticket_id : req.body.ticket_id
}
}).then(function(tickets) {
if (tickets) {
    for (var i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
        models.ticketdevice_map.create({
            ticket_id : tickets.dataValues.ticket_id,
            device_id : devices[i].device_id,
            reg_color : devices[i].reg_color
        });
    }
  }
});
```